# Is this special line graph of a graph a known concept?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph. We form a graph $H=(V',E')$ from $G$ such that

- $V' = V \cup \{ w_e \mid e \in E \}$, and
- $E' = \{ aw_e, bw_e \mid ab = e \in E \} \cup \{ w_e w_f \mid e,f \text{ are adjacent edges in }G \}$.

Informally, $H$ is built from $G$ by subdividing each edge, and by putting an edge between two newly created vertices iff the corresponding edges are adjacent in $G$.

The above construction feels quite natural. Does it have a name? It seems like some kind of a variation of the line graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph is a subgraph of the [total graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalGraph.html) of $G$.  Both graphs have the same vertex set, and each edge in your graph is an edge in the total graph, but yours is missing edges for all the vertex-vertex adjacencies in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

The graph $H$ is isomorphic to the [intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph) of $V\cup E$.

Comment: It seems this is known as the [middle graph](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_551.html).